# Azure media services Encoding - Codec not supported

Tags: c#, azure, video-encoding, azure-media-services

I am trying to convert 3gp2 file - to  `"H264 Broadband 720p"`
and this result into `UserInput : File type or codec not supported.`
I have used VLC to understand of what kind of codecs are in this media -
there are

```
Stream 0:
Type Video
Codec: MPEG-4 Video (mp4v)
resolution 170x160
number of frames 25
decoded formate: Planar 4:2:0 YUV
Stream 1: 
Type: Audio
Codec: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)
Chennels: Stereo
Frequency of detalization: 44100 Hz
```

I have looked to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-azure-media-encoder-formats/ 
both of `mp4v` and `aac`  are supported.
Perhaps anyone have had the same problem with 3gp2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you uploading via the Azure Portal, or using Azure Media Explorer tool, or code?

Which encoder are you using? If Portal, it would be our older encoder which does not support all 3gp2 file formats. Likely a container bug that we wont fix in the older encoder

The portal is being updated to use our latest encoder  - Media Encoder Standard this week.

My recommendation is to use the Media Encoder Standard encoder via http://aka.ms/amse tool or through code. Or wait a few days and use the portal again if you prefer that route.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear.  Let me know if you need anything else.